# C# regular expression '+' character

Tags: c#, regex

How do I use C# regular expressions to search for special characters (like '+' in this case)?

I would usually just use + in perl / ruby, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in C#.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use backslash to escape special characters

Comment: But don't forget that in C# you'll either need to escape the backslash itself or use a verbatim string literal. So you'd need either `"\\+"` or `@"\+"` to match `+`.

Comment: Yeah, I usually use @ for regex strings

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes work fine. As an alternative, you could use a character class for this and use `[+]` to match "+".